# How to pass array of inputs to web api via angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Angularjs and learning webapi by building a service which retrieves data(Movie details) to user.
**Movie Name**, **Year**, **Ratings** and **Cast** are the parameters.
I'm trying to do **POST** call using `form`. I used text boxes for all inputs and when do submit, Cast value is being passed as null as it defined as `Array` datatype.
**Note** : I let user to enter `Cast` values by comma separated.
**Eg** : `Cena, Orton, Edge` 
Here I stuck how to take values entered in `Cast` control and pass to my webapi as an array object.

**HTML:**

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="moviename" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="year" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="rating" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="cast" />
   <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.avalue = [];
$scope.submit = function() {
    var prod = {
        "Name": $scope.moviename,
        "Year": $scope.year,
        "Rating": $scope.rating,
        "Cast": $scope.avalue
    };
    var result = CRUDService.Add(prod);
};
```

How It could be achieved. by the way of comma separation in `Cast` input??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to split a String into an array of Substrings. Based on the input you expect, this may work:

```
$scope.avalue = $scope.cast.split(', ');
$scope.submit = function() {
  var prod = {
    "Name": $scope.moviename,
    "Year": $scope.year,
    "Rating": $scope.rating,
    "Cast": $scope.avalue
  };
  var result = CRUDService.Add(prod);
};
```